# Custom UILabel View not updating it's frame in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, custom-view

I'm trying to create a UILabel for Font Awesome, which seems to work well so far. The issue I'm having is that when I change the font size for the label in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`, it's not reflected in the Interface Builder.

This is my code:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class FALabel : UILabel {

    @IBInspectable
    private var icon: String = ""

    @IBInspectable
    private var weight: NSInteger = 0

    /**
     * The type for the Font Awesome Label
     */
    enum FAType {
        case Brands
        case Light
        case Regular
        case Solid
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the view or the Interface Builder.
     */
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }

    /**
     * Set up the view.
     */
    func setupView() {
        let type: FAType =  {
            switch self.weight {
            case 0:  return .Light
            case 2:  return .Solid
            case 3:  return .Brands
            default: return .Regular
            }
        }()

        setFontAwesomeIcon(faType: type, size: self.font.pointSize, icon: FAIcons.iconNamed(name: self.icon))
        self.sizeToFit()
        self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.minX, y:self.frame.minY, width:self.frame.width, height:self.frame.height)
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the intrinsic content size.
     */
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    }

    /**
     * Set the Font Awesome Icon for the label.
     *
     * - parameter fatype: The type to set.
     * - parameter size:   The size for the font.
     * - parameter icon:   The icon to use.
     */
    func setFontAwesomeIcon(faType: FAType, size: CGFloat, icon:String) {
        if faType == .Regular {
            self.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Pro-Regular", size: size)
        } else if faType == .Solid {
            self.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Pro-Solid", size: size)
        } else if faType == .Light {
            self.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Pro-Light", size: size)
        } else if faType == .Brands {
            self.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Brands-Regular", size: size)
        }
        self.text = icon
    }
}
```

When I change anything in the Interface Builder, the frame seems to stay the same size but the icon itself is drawn larger like I want.

[image: preview of problem]

I thought that calling `self.sizeToFit()` from `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` should resize the view and change those `15x18` dimensions, but it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that any size related adjustments should be put in `layoutSubviews`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   setupView()
}
```

You might use `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` to populate some samples data, for example to preview in the IB, but you shouldn’t recall the setup you already did in `init` methods (like `setupView()`).

You can also omit the `init` methods I guess and simplify everything down to:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class FALabel : UILabel {

    @IBInspectable
    public var icon: String = "" { 
        didSet { setupView() } 
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var weight: NSInteger = 0 { 
        didSet { setupView() } 
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupView()
    }

    /**
     * The type for the Font Awesome Label
     */
    enum FAType {
        case Brands
        case Light
        case Regular
        case Solid
    }

    /**
     * Set up the view.
     */
    func setupView() {
        let type: FAType =  {
            switch self.weight {
            case 0:  return .Light
            case 2:  return .Solid
            case 3:  return .Brands
            default: return .Regular
            }
        }()

        setFontAwesomeIcon(faType: type, size: self.font.pointSize, icon: FAIcons.iconNamed(name: self.icon))
        self.sizeToFit()
        self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.minX, y:self.frame.minY, width:self.frame.width, height:self.frame.height)
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the intrinsic content size.
     */
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    }

    /**
     * Set the Font Awesome Icon for the label.
     *
     * - parameter fatype: The type to set.
     * - parameter size:   The size for the font.
     * - parameter icon:   The icon to use.
     */
    func setFontAwesomeIcon(faType: FAType, size: CGFloat, icon:String) {
        if faType == .Regular {
            self.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Pro-Regular", size: size)
        } else if faType == .Solid {
            self.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Pro-Solid", size: size)
        } else if faType == .Light {
            self.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Pro-Light", size: size)
        } else if faType == .Brands {
            self.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Brands-Regular", size: size)
        }
        self.text = icon
    }
}
```